# How to convert ast.Tuple to a list

Tags: python

I tried to convert an ast.Tuple into a list by doing this

```
mylist = list(mytuple)
```

However, I am getting a `Tuple object is not iterable` error. Is there a way to convert this tuple into a list?

The tuple in question is a `Tuple` of `ast` objects, one being type `ast.Str`, the other being `ast.Name`. My ultimate goal is to create a string of the two. However, there might be situations where there are more than two elements in the tuple so I need to be able to iterate over the tuple to check what type of `ast` object each element is.

This is the error message from the python interpreter

```
TypeError: 'Tuple' object is not iterable
```

This is the code that produced the error

```
if type(foo) is ast.Tuple:
    g = list(foo)
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, looks like they removed the quotes from the exception message. I get `TypeError: 'Tuple' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree with your characterization of the question as "off topic". there may be information missing, but this seems like an extreme and unbalanced reaction. At any rate, as I will update in the OP, the object is type ast.Tuple: `if type(foo) is ast.Tuple:`, which may explain why it's not iterable.

Comment: @Leahcim: A question is easily reopened. Your question is incomplete and can't be answered in it's current form. It is off-topic.

Comment: @Leahcim: yes, `ast` syntax tree nodes are not meant to be iterable. So the answer is: you don't *have* a tuple. Why are you trying to convert `ast.Tuple` into a list? What output did you expect?

Comment: @Leahcim Try `mytuple.elts`, that should give you a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `tuple`. You have an [`ast.Node` subclass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#node-classes). This *does matter*, AST nodes represent a parse tree, and although `ast.Tuple` may, in running Python code, result in a `tuple()` instance, there the relationship ends. A parse tree is an intermediary stage between source code and bytecode, and only *executed* bytecode produces actual tuples.

AST node classes only have the attributes documented in the `ast` module documentation and are not iterable. You can access the `_fields`, `lineno` and `col_offset` attributes, where `_fields` is an iterable.

For a specific `ast.Node` subclass, consult the [*Abstract Grammar* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) to see what other types of nodes are passed in for that node, and by what names those other objects can be accessed. For `ast.Tuple` that grammar is:

```
Tuple(expr* elts, expr_context ctx)
```

so `elts` and `ctx` will be available as two attributes, and `elts` is a sequence as well. Incidentally, the `ast.Node._fields` attribute names those attributes as well.

If you are looking for the 'contents' of a tuple as parsed into the tree, look no further than `elts`; this is already a list:

```
>>> import ast
>>> tree = ast.parse('("foo", bar)')
>>> tree.body[0].value
<_ast.Tuple object at 0x10262f990>
>>> tree.body[0].value._fields
('elts', 'ctx')
>>> tree.body[0].value.elts
[<_ast.Str object at 0x10262f910>, <_ast.Name object at 0x10262f6d0>]
```